# Bootstrap 5 Modal not working in Electron

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, bootstrap-modal

I'm using bootstrap 5 in my web app and the modal is not showing up.

Here is the HTML for my modal and for the button activating it:

```
<div
          class="modal"
          tabindex="-1"
          id="newInstallModal"
          aria-labelledby="settings"
        >
          <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn-close"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                  aria-label="Close"
                ></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                <p>Modal body text goes here.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button
                  type="button"
                  class="btn btn-secondary"
                  data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                >
                  Close
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                  Save changes
                </button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <input
          id="newInstallButton"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-outline-primary"
          value="New Install"
        />
```

And here is the typescript code assigning that bootstrap-5 provided to open the modal via js.

```
newInstallModal = <HTMLDivElement>document.getElementById("newInstallModal");
newInstallButton = <HTMLButtonElement>document.getElementById("newInstallButton");

newInstallModal.addEventListener("show.bs.modal", () => {
   newInstallButton.focus();
})
```

Any help is good, because I'm done debugging for today.

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap-modal v5 [usage](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#usage):

Either you have to use `data-` attributes:

```html
<button type="button" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#newInstallModal">Launch modal</button>
```

OR via script:

```js
var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('newInstallModal'), options)
```

EDIT: Also

```js
myModal.addEventListener('shown.bs.modal', ...)
```

is just an eventlistener for when the modal is shown (after show transition ended)

Comment: See, here is the problem.  I have tried to use both, and with the way my app is currently set up neither is working.  I have to think it's a compatibility issue between this bootstrap module and electron as everything else I've tried to do with bootstrap has worked fine.  I know that the modal is supposed to use js to function, so maybe I'm not importing a script somewhere?  I've tried at least a couple of the bootstrap scripts, so if you could point out which one I should be importing to the HTML (if that is the case) that'd be great.

Comment: @MCRM You should (IMO) include a CDN script. Refer to this link: [Introduction (js)](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/introduction/#js) NOTE: "Place one of the following <script>s near the end of your pages, right before the closing </body> tag, to enable them"